# Bind one Dropdown based on another Dropdown SelectedValue inside DataList - c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, datalist

I am using 3 `DropDownList` inside `DataList`. So, each row contains 3 `DropDownList`. `DataList` also contains `DataKeyField`.
Now, if user select value from `DropDownList1` then I want to bind `DropDownList2` and if user select value from `DropDownList2` then I want to bind `DropDownList3`. I am using `SelectedIndexChanged` and I am able to get value of related `DropDownList` selected value. But, If user select `DropDownList2` then I also need value of `DropDownList1` and also need value of respected `DataKeyField`.
How to get this ???

**My code Sample:**

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlTest" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dlTest_ItemDataBound"
        DataKeyField="TestId">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"> </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged"> </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged"> </asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Here, `onSelectedIndexChanged` of `DropDownList3`, I am able to get selectedValue of it but I also need respected row's selectedValue of `DropDownList1` and `DropDownList2` and also respected `DataKeyField` value.

```
protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var DropDownList3 = (DropDownList)sender;

        string DDL3 = ((DropDownList)DropDownList3.NamingContainer.FindControl("DropDownList3")).SelectedValue;
        // Also need selectedValue of DropDownList1 and DropDownList2 and DataKeyField.
    }
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you pretty much have the code right there. Instead of `.FindControl("DropDownList3")`, just do a find control for "DropDownList1" and "DropDownList2".

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost there. You just need to. Using your code:

```
protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)sender;
    var DropDownList2 = (DropDownList)sender;
    var DropDownList3 = (DropDownList)sender;

    string DDL1 = ((DropDownList)DropDownList1.NamingContainer.FindControl("DropDownList1")).SelectedValue;
    string DDL2 = ((DropDownList)DropDownList2.NamingContainer.FindControl("DropDownList2")).SelectedValue;
    string DDL3 = ((DropDownList)DropDownList3.NamingContainer.FindControl("DropDownList3")).SelectedValue;
}
```

Either way I would do it a little bit different:

```
    item valueddl1 = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
```

And so on; which should work as weel and it is a little bit more simple.

Comment: Creating three variables for the same object and naming them as objects that are in fact different in the markup is unnecessary and confusing. I wouldn't recommend doing this. Also, the OP asked how to get the DataKeyField value, so you should include that in your answer as well.